# Including a controller method returning a view on blade template

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have been working with Laravel for a while now.

However, I am faced with a new challenge. I have some notifications in my application which are going to be shown on the master template.

In this scenario, it'd be great being able to include `NotificationController@getNotifications` returning af view containing the notifications.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you elaborate on the user journey on how you see this working and perhaps I can help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should include any controller to achieve this. Controllers are supposed to handle user requests. I think a [composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) is the way to go.

Create a composer for your master template that will provide the view with the notifications you want to be shown.

```
View::composer('layouts.master', function($view)
{
    $notifications = Notification::all();
    $view->with('notifications', $notifications);
});
```

Then render the notifications in the template file.

Another way to do this, is to add a composer to the notifications view and then include that view from the master template (using [@include](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures)).

*Note:* Laravel doesn't provide a file or folder for composers to be in by default. I usually create a *composers.php* or a *composers* folder (for class based composers).